# Rewrite rule - but only if to a certain url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule in my htacces that rewrites POST http authorization requests and converts it in to a get request. But this happens to every http auth request.

I actually only need it to rewrite if it is going to the www.mysite.com/googlecheckout/api url:

This is what I currently have:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .*
RewriteRule index.php index.php?login=%{HTTP:Authorization}

This does work but it messes up a couple of other pages elsewhere.

Any one know how to achieve this?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
RewriteRule ^googlecheckout/api$ index.php?login=%{HTTP:Authorization}
```